# Retrieve community tab data with the YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to retrieve posts and comments from the tab community using the YouTube Data API?

Regards,
Lotfi Zaouai

Comment: The short answer: no, currently that's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Data API is not returning comments from Community tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189374/youtube-data-api-is-not-returning-comments-from-community-tab)