# YouTube Data API is not returning comments from Community tab

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi YouTube Data API Team -

The `commentsThread` endpoint (`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads`) is not returning comments from the Community tab in YouTube.

I've debugged this extensively, trying just the `channelId` parameter instead and the comments from the Community tab simply do not return on the API call.

The channel ID is `UC7kCeZ53sli_9XwuQeFxLqw` and the querystring parameters I send to the `commentsThread` endpoint on an HTTP GET are as follows:

```
part: snippet,replies
allThreadsRelatedToChannelId: UC7kCeZ53sli_9XwuQeFxLqw
key: {YT_API_KEY}
maxResults: 100
```

Is there a different API endpoint for Community tab post comments/replies or is there a bug in the endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: *This is not YouTube Data API team.* W.r.t. your question, *the answer is unfortunately negative:* there's not API endpoint that'll provide your the comments on a channel's community tab.

Comment: @stvar https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: Quote from the very page you linked above, @Ashely: *[**Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). 
Something wrong? Send us a bug report!* Again, SO is not Google support.

Comment: [ticket posted on issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200065968) - select the star at the upper-left corner for highlight the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) you will notice it says

> Returns a list of comment threads that match the API request parameters.

The comments.list method is the same.  This is a list of comments on each video.

There is currently no end point to request information on the community tab.  You may want to consider checking if there is already a feature request for it if not then you could submit one [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)

Answer (score 1):

As [@DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) said there isn't any endpoint doing exactly what you want. However if you check the documentation for [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) you will notice it says

> The **allThreadsRelatedToChannelId** parameter instructs the API to return all comment threads associated with the specified channel. **The response can include comments about the channel or about the channel's videos.**

That way if you consider the channel with `channelId` `UCqPkQu3N8OqYKC5wwE6CmGQ` you can recover the community tab comments by such a YouTube Data API v3 request with commentThreads endpoint: `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UCqPkQu3N8OqYKC5wwE6CmGQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can distinguish comments on videos from comments in the community tab by checking whether or not a `videoId` is defined in snippet of each item.

Pay attention to precise `part=snippet` otherwise you won't receive any community tab comment.

Comment: Have you actually done this Benjamin? This is literally the request I sent to the API and it does not return comments from the Community tab.

Comment: Yes I tested. Check out "graphically" my Community tab comment at https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqPkQu3N8OqYKC5wwE6CmGQ/discussion "Benjamin Loison - 1 day ago - This is a community tab comment written by Benjamin Loison." and you can also check it **currently as the first item of the YouTube Data API v3 request I wrote in my answer**. Make sure to precise ` snippet` in `part` of your request.

Comment: Don't hesitate to give a minimal reproducible request if you can't make my approach work.